# loopback w/ table schemas, not identifying schema in options

Tags: db2, loopbackjs

**Nature of the issue**

My db2 database makes wide use of table schemas for organization, so the table in question is LIVE.TBLADDRESS -

My model uses the "options" to specify the table schema

```
"options": {
    "idInjection": false,
    "db2": {
        "schema": "LIVE",
        "table": "TBLADDRESS"
    }
}
```

the model is in the model-config.json using

```
,"Tbladdress": {
    "dataSource": "x3",
    "public": true
}
```

I get an error when I try to use the explorer to do a simple 'get' or any other API call.

```
"statusCode": 500,
"name": "Error",
"message": "[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0204N "DB2X.TBLADDRESS" is an undefined name. SQLSTATE=42704\r\n",
```

**Expected behavior**

Once I specified the schema - I'd expect the API to resolve correctly

**Actual behavior**

The default schema for db user is used at all times...regardless of specified schema in options.

**Suggested resolution**

Maybe I set it in the wrong place, I will continue to look for the information, It is possible I am missing something.

This is what I "see" using DB Viewer...so you have an idea what I'm referring to.

```
DEV - host:50000/DEV
-schemas
|-AAA
|-BBB
|-DB2X (this is the schema that the error is referring to...but NOT the one specified in the model)
|-DDD
|-LIVE (this is the correct schema)
|--Tables
|--|-TBLA
|--|-TBLADDRESS
|-ZZZ
```

If it helps - this happens with manually create models or models generated by discovery scripts.

These are my config files, and model

**/common/models/Tbladdress.json**

```
{
    "name": "Tbladdress",
    "options": {
        "idInjection": false,
        "db2": {
            "schema": "LIVE",
            "table": "TBLADDRESS"
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        ...
    }
}
```

**/datasources.json**

```
{
    "db": {
        "name": "db",
        "connector": "memory"
    },
    "x3": {
        "name": "x3",
        "connector": "db2",
        "username": "...",
        "password": "...",
        "database": "...",
        "hostname": "...",
        "port":     50000
    }
}
```

**/model-config.json**

```
{
    "_meta": {
    ...
    },
    "User": {
        "dataSource": "db"
    },
    "AccessToken": {
        "dataSource": "db",
        "public": false
    },
    "ACL": {
        "dataSource": "db",
        "public": false
    },
    "RoleMapping": {
        "dataSource": "db",
        "public": false,
        "options": {
            "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
        }
    },
    "Role": {
        "dataSource": "db",
        "public": false
    }

    ,"Tbladdress": {
        "dataSource": "x3",
        "public": true
    }

}
```

http://localhost:3000/explorer/#!/Tbladdress/Tbladdress_findById

```
{
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 500,
        "name": "Error",
        "message": "[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0204N  \"DB2X.TBLADDRESS\" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704\r\n",
        "errors": [],
        "error": "[node-ibm_db] SQL_ERROR",
        "state": "42S02",
        "stack": "Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0204N  \"DB2X.TBLADDRESS\" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704\r\n"
    }
}
```

**...Headers...**

```
{
    "date": "Sun, 18 Feb 2018 05:20:36 GMT",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-download-options": "noopen",
    "x-frame-options": "DENY",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
    "vary": "Origin, Accept-Encoding",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
}
```

**USING:**

*loopback-cli v3* to generate express app

*loopback-connector-db2* to connect to DB2 v10

*Node v8.9.2*

Package.JSON dependencies looks like this (as mentioned it's a default install, with one model added - to see if I could get it to work)

```
"dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "helmet": "^1.3.0",
    "loopback": "^3.0.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^5.0.0",
    "loopback-connector-db2": "^2.1.1",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "strong-error-handler": "^2.0.0"
```

},

Yes - the DB2 connector worked fine when I specified the "LIVE" schema on data discovery - but it does NOT seem to be working when I use the API. I don't know if it's the connector or the loopback app.

Comment: It may help to enumerate all the software-components you are using, and their versions ( all layers ). In particular, are you using loopback-connector-db2 - because it supports the 'schema' connector property.

Comment: @mao - added. thx.

Comment: In your datasources.json, for source x3, have you tried `"schema" : "LIVE", ` ?  Is the loopback API stuff documented to be fully multi-schema aware?

Comment: @mao - I did try "schema" : "LIVE" in the  datasources.json, for source x3 - no change in behavior - same error. - I am unaware if it is documented to be fully 'multi-schema aware' - but the docs mention model differences, and they uses "options schema.." to define models for Oracle... So I assume it is

Comment: I guess I'm really looking for someone who is using loopback against a DB2 DB. I'd think/hope the IBM guys who took over the project would be hitting their own product...and DB2 requires schema(s).. so I'm sure it may be something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It is open source so if you have the skill you can trace what is happening in the API. Failing that, you may need to wait for your Issue on github to get a response.   As a temporary workaround, at Db2 level you can create aliases from your own default-schema to the real target objects in different schemas, which is only valid if the same-object can't appear in multiple schemas.

Comment: @mao - yes, I've been delving into it to try to find the problem, I'll admit I get in pretty deep, but it exceeded my skill set - so I posted here, hoping someone had done what I'm attempting, or had some knowledge, Thx for the input.

Comment: Take a look at the [source code that creates the connection string](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-ibmdb/blob/master/lib/ibmdb.js#L95-L100). I never used db2, but it appears the connection string is appended with `;CurrentSchema=SCHEMA`, where `SCHEMA` is either your defined schema or username. Given the code I'm looking at, it appears you need to set `"schema": "LIVE"` in your datasources.json config. But, you said you've already tried that. Can you put in some breakpoints around this connection string, and debug what is being generated?

Comment: Thank you Andrew - I will try it again...and dig around a bit looking for that currentSchema ... hopefully today.

Comment: @andrew Ferk - Thx - that worked....If you post it, I'll select it as the correct answer - and upvote it. What I had tried earlier was "currentSchema", not just "schema" in the datasource (or if I did rey it, I didn't restart the server, so it appeared to not work) - Regardless - specifying the schema as "schema" in the datasource.json, did the job, granted I have to set up a separate datasource for EACH schema - seems stupid, because you specify it in the model.... but hey. - thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `loopback-connector-db2`, you must define `SCHEMA` in the `datasources.json` config file.

```
{
  "x3": {
    "name": "x3",
    "connector": "db2",
    "username": "...",
    "password": "...",
    "database": "...",
    "hostname": "...",
    "port":     50000
  },
  "x3Live": {
    "name": "x3Live",
    "connector": "db2",
    "schema": "LIVE",
    "username": "...",
    "password": "...",
    "database": "...",
    "hostname": "...",
    "port":     50000
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, you will need to create a new datasource (e.g. `x3Live`). Use the old `x3` datasource for the models using the `DB2X` schema, and the new `x3Live` datasource for the models using the `LIVE` schema.